# Return value in between two strings

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, str-replace

I know this may be a common question but I can't find the exact answer I want.

I have the following string.

```
#|First Name|#
Random Text
#|Last Name|#
```

What I would like to do is have all the values that are in between the `#|` & `|#` and replace the whole string with a value. This must be in an array so I can loop through them all.

So as an example I have:

```
#|First Name|#
```

After processing I would like it to be:

```
John
```

So the main logic would be to use the First Name value to print out a value from a database.

Can someone help me out here.

This is code I've tried:

```
preg_match('/#|(.*)|#/i', $html, $ret);
```

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't you need preg_match_all for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) for this, in addition to making your regex non-greedy and escaping the vertical bar:

```
$replacements = array( 'John', 'Smith');
$index = 0;
$output = preg_replace_callback('/#\|(.*?)\|#/i', function( $match) use ($replacements, &$index) {
    return $replacements[$index++];    
}, $input);
```

This [will output](http://viper-7.com/JRnR1O):

```
string(24) "John
Random Text
Smith"
```

Comment: The call back parameters is throwing an error for me.. `syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION`

Comment: @Sandeep - You have an older PHP version that doesn't support anonymous functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = '#|First Name|#
Random Text
#|Last Name|#';
$search = array(
    '#|First Name|#',
    '#|Last Name|#',
);
$replace = array(
    'John',
    'Smith',
);
$string = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

Comment: +1 This is a more efficient solution if all of the searches are known beforehand.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I need a regex as the `First Name` & `Last Name` can be named something else, and I wouldn't know as it'll be picked out from a custom table